# Angular Material: Use colors from themes for background

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to apply for the Angular Material `mat-button-toggle` a background-color different to the standard. I have currently

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

$app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$app-primary-light:  mat-palette($mat-indigo, A200, A100, A400);
$app-purple: mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);

$app-theme: mat-light-theme($app-primary, $app-primary-light);

@mixin mix-app-theme($app-theme) {
  $primary: map-get($app-theme, primary);
  $purple: map-get($app-theme, warn);

  .mat-button-toggle {
    background-color: mat-color($primary);
    color: mat-color($primary, default-contrast);
  }
  .mat-button-toggle.purple {
    background-color: mat-color($purple, 700);
  }
```

I found a [list](http://%20%20%20%20//%20https://material.io/archive/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette) of available themes. Now I would like to apply for the `mat-button-toggle` the color from `Deep Purple`. Somehow the `$purple` doesn't work and I have no clue how to extract the colors properly.

What is the correct syntax to extract it from `Deep Purple`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `$purple` varibale is a map.
You can get one color with the `map-get` function:

```
.mat-button-toggle.purple {
    background-color: map-get($purple, 700);
}
```

Comment: Yeah... but .... First of all - no clue how to address the `DeepPurple` theme. Next I'm not really sure how to include it and how to address it. If I just use your syntax I use the `warn`  colors. Which I didn't find very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out that I need to include the defined theme into the `$app-theme` - than I can use it quite easily:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

$app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$app-purple: mat-palette($mat-deep-purple);

$app-theme: mat-light-theme($app-primary, $app-purple);

// https://material.io/archive/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette

@mixin mix-app-theme($app-theme) {
  $primary: map-get($app-theme, primary);

  .mat-button-toggle {
    background-color: mat-color($primary);
    color: mat-color($primary, default-contrast);
  }
  .mat-button-toggle.purple {
    background-color: mat-color($app-purple, 700);
  }
```